# Using LMR62421XMF to boost Li-ion voltage from 3.3V to 7.5V@0.5A but voltage droops

Tags: power-supply, boost

While designing using the [LMR62421](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmr62421.pdf) for boosting from 3.6V to 7.5V, I followed the typical circuit from the datasheet (below) and simulated it on WORK bench for 0.5A.

[image: schematic]

When used practically for a load of 15 ohms, it is getting loaded and the  voltage droops to 6V. I found that it does not support more than 100mA. Is there anything I missed out in the design or do I need to change the circuit from the typical?

- R1=10K
- R2=51K
- C3=470pF
- C1=C2=22uF ceramic caps
- L1=10uH 56 mohms & 2.5A
- D1=[SS14](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/SS19-D.PDF)

I require help as I am stuck and the design needs to be released ASAP.

Apology for delayed edit:
Found issue in the layout and updated the same. Please find below layout images and inductor details:
[image: Bottom Layer]
[image: Top Layer]
[image: Inductor details]

Comment: Welcome :-) Please edit your question (click the "edit" link below the question) and [add clear images](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#images) of your PCB layout, and clear photos of the hardware you are actually testing. Also please add a link to the datasheet for your inductor. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing obvious wrong. PCB layout may matter. L1 should be checked for Imax. You say 2.5A but if it saturates lower than this it can cause problems. Remove C3 temporarily. This ensures faster transient response but conceivably may affect stability. Probably not.  View waveforms with an oscilloscope. Note frequency is high (~= 2 MHz) and inductor core must be rated for this. Datasheets for all parts always helps.

Comment: Pankaj D - Hi, Your question said that the design "*needs to be released ASAP*", but you didn't reply to my request for information after almost 3 days (so far). Perhaps you have got an answer elsewhere. Due to that lack of response, with regret, I'm voting to close as "needs details".

Comment: @SamGibson _"I require help"_ didn't go unnoticed too.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't saturating your inductor?

Comment: @Winny : My calculation considers worst case peak to be less than 2.1A  including including ripple current. inductor rating is 2.3A. Hope this should be fine. If not need to change inductor of higher ratings. In simulation seen max current on WEBENCH to be 1.4A.

Comment: Good. Probably not the inductor then.